# Override i18next TFunction using an enum from an other file

Tags: typescript, i18next

I'm trying to override the [TFunction](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/9f53732ab9bbad57f7d0bda2ed85316a4bee8a2c/index.d.ts#L655) of the [i18next package](https://github.com/i18next/i18next).

What I'm trying to achieve is ensuring typing of the used i18n keys as:

```
t('invalid-key') // is invalid
t('key1') // is valid
```

So I made the following `i18next.d.ts` file to override the type of the TFunction:

```
type Keys = 'key1' | 'key2'

declare module 'i18next' {
    export type TFunction = (key: Keys) => string
}
```

It works but as soon as I try import that type from an other file the TFunction type goes back to the original one.

Does someone have a hint to help me import the keys in the declaration file?

---

Oddly import works when I do it through the [useTranslation](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/364653c5530431e7c946d332baf2f5b3b3a7caae/src/index.d.ts#L60) hook of the [react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next) package:

```
import { I18nKey } from '../modules/core/i18n/i18nKey'

declare module 'react-i18next' {
    export function useTranslation(): {
        t: (key: I18nKey) => string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you export `Keys` in the declaration file, the declaration file will become a module. This causes TypeScript to not include the file globally. Make a separate file for the `declare module` to include globally.

---

If you want to import in a global file that declares a module you should import them inside the module like this.

```
declare module 'react-i18next' {
    import { I18nKey } from '../modules/core/i18n/i18nKey'

    export function useTranslation(): {
        t: (key: I18nKey) => string
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems creating a separate file for the Keys type and importing it in the declaration file also make it become module. Did I missed something to create the declaration file without `export` and `import`?

Comment: If you use either import or export it automatically becomes an import. Therefore you should not import anything to the global type file. Either it's a module or it's not. Please describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: I simply want to declare the hundreds of keys along the multiple modules of my app. Then, use them in the declaration file to avoid misspelling when using the TFunction. I have made an edit of the question to show how the import works when I do it for the `react-i18next` package. I don't understand why.